# system information to workspace

Tags: octave

How to return to a variable the information of the system command, like:

```
a=system("cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model name' | uniq")
return a=0
```

or

```
b=system("xrandr | grep 'current'")
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 16384 x 16384
ans = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

As documented in Octave, you can get the result in a variable if this one is the second output.
Example: with

```
[s, r] = system("ls")
```

you get in `r` the expected list of file names.